# Moving URLs and files on the server: Do I need to change something in the database before the move?

Tags: url, database, server-setup, base-url, testing

I have purchased some disk space and two domains from my hosting
provider. I am currently not using a dedicated IP + SSL certificate
because I am just testing. In fact both of the following two sites
are used for testing, but I need to move my Magento site from
SITE1 to SITE2:

```
SITE1
Domain: world.com
WebSite Root Directory (where magento is installed): ~/public_html

SITE2
Domain: hello.com (alternatively I could also configure SITE2 to be
  served from hello.world.com or world.com/hello via cPanel, and save
  world.com for some other site)
WebSite Root Directory (where magento needs to be moved to): ~/public_html/hello
```

Will I run into any trouble if I carry out the above operation?
I am particularly concerned with having to change URLs in the Magento database
(namely any references to world.com to hello.com).

Comment: In particular I need to know whether I need to change the System -> Configuration -> Web -> Base URL prior to (or after) the move. Thanks.

Comment: You could save yourself some time moving away from cpanel to normal hosting. Without cpanel the convention to to have your base directory in /var/www/yoursite. Then it comes to editing your virtual host definitions to tell apache/nginx of your site name/basedir. On the Magento side you then need to edit the URLs in core_config_data.

Comment: @woolfie you are referencing conventions I've never seen in real life. I've seen `/var/www/vhosts/example.com`, though. CPanel is not a factor here. @john_sonderson Why are you using two different full installations instead of creating a multistore with the same code base?

Comment: The reason I am not running a multistore is that rather than a single store I am simply setting up a collection of completely independent sites to showcase clients.

Comment: So if I change the URL via Apache (or my provider's interface for managing domains and subdomains) then I need only change core_config_data and I do not need to touch the MySQL database. What is core_config_data and what file can I find this variable in? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not too sure about how to change the code or database to accomodate the change in URLs. Perhaps I would appreciate some help in this regard. The core_config_data you mentioned is declared as a constant named ENTITY in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Data.php and appears in various config.xml files such as app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml but I don't know what to do with this. If I view the database with phpMyAdmin can I find the data I need to change to reflect the change in URL? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

John, to update the URL in your database you first need to **BE VERY CAREFUL!**

I would recommend making a complete backup of your database first.

Since you are on cPanel you can use PHPMyAdmin to login to your database. You can run the following command in MySQL to find your urls

```
select * from core_config_data where value like 'http%';
```

This will give a dozen or so results, but the important ones will be your site urls that you want to change.

```
mysql> select * from core_config_data where value like 'http%';
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                                    | value                                               |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|        61 | default |        0 | carriers/ups/gateway_xml_url            | https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Rate        |
|        65 | default |        0 | carriers/ups/gateway_url                | http://www.ups.com/using/services/rave/qcostcgi.cgi |
|        70 | default |        0 | carriers/ups/tracking_xml_url           | https://www.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track               |
|        85 | default |        0 | carriers/usps/gateway_url               | http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll  |
|       104 | default |        0 | carriers/fedex/gateway_url              | https://gateway.fedex.com/GatewayDC                 |
|       123 | default |        0 | carriers/dhl/gateway_url                | https://eCommerce.airborne.com/ApiLandingTest.asp   |
|       552 | default |        0 | payment/authorizenet/cgi_url            | https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll   |
|       564 | default |        0 | payment/verisign/url                    | https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com/transaction     |
|       675 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_url                   | http://www.domain.com/                          |
|       676 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_url                     | https://www.domain.com/                         |
|      1361 | default |        0 | payment/authorizenet_directpost/cgi_url | https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll   |
|      1377 | default |        0 | carriers/ups/shipconfirm_xml_url        | https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipConfirm |
|      1378 | default |        0 | carriers/ups/shipaccept_xml_url         | https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/ShipAccept  |
|      1385 | default |        0 | carriers/usps/gateway_secure_url        | https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll     |
|      1404 | default |        0 | carriers/dhlint/gateway_url             | https://xmlpi-ea.dhl.com/XMLShippingServlet         |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The other way to do it is to look for the web/secure and web/unsecure paths

In the example you can see my domains is config_id 675 and 676

So to update it in phpMyAdmin I think you can click on the field and edit (I am not 100% sure)

Or you can run the following command

```
update core_config_data set value = 'http://mynewdomain.com/' where config_id in (675,676);
```

If you need secure and unsecure then you would do :

```
update core_config_data set value = 'http://mynewdomain.com/' where config_id = 675;
update core_config_data set value = 'https://mynewdomain.com/' where config_id = 676;
```

Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can do it pretty easily with a simple `sed` command on the `sql` file,

```
sed -i 's/www.mydomain.com/new.mydomain.com/g' db.sql
```

#### Full example with `sed`

Go to home dir,

```
cd /home/sonassi/public_html
```

Grab DB dump utility,

```
wget -O mage-dbdump.sh sys.sonassi.com/mage-dbdump.sh
chmod +x mage-dbdump.sh
./mage-dbdump.sh -d
```

Move DB dump to staging/dev/new site

```
mv ./var/db.sql ../subdomains/staging/var/db.sql
mv ./mage-dbdump.sh ../subdomains/staging/
cd ../subdomains/staging/
```

Replace URLs in DB dump

```
sed -i 's/www.mydomain.com/staging.mydomain.com/g' ./var/db.sql
```

Restore the DB

```
./mage-dbdump.sh -r
```

#### Example with `n98-MageRun`

Or if you use [MageRun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) (which is a fantastic *must have* utility), then you can use it to change Magento configuration settings

```
./magerun config:set web/unsecure/base_url new.mydomain.com
./magerun config:set web/secure/base_url new.mydomain.com
./magerun cache:flush
```

---

Source: https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/our-magento-git-guide-and-work-flow/